# Unterschied zwischen "schildern" und "beschreiben"

Tags: difference, word-choice, verb

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Verben *schildern* und *beschreiben*?
Handelt es sich bei schildern, abgeleitet von Schild, um eine bildhafte Erzählung oder um eine, die auf die Landschaft oder das Aussehen betont?
Korrigieren Sie bitte die Frage, wenn etwas darin nicht stimmt.

Comment: Ich finde das eine interessante Frage. Kommt *schildern* von einer alten Praxis - als viele Leute noch nicht lesen konnten - ihnen Dinge (wie biblische Geschichten wohl hauptsächlich) nicht in Textform sondern auf "Schildern" (gemalten Tafeln) zu vermitteln?

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch?

Comment: Eventuell gibt es einen Zusammenhang mit ndl. _schilderen_ = _malen_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*»Schildern«* wird im Allgemeinen dann verwendet, wenn jemand eine ausführliche Beschreibung abgibt, meist mündlich, auch schriftlich. Die [Schilderung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schilderung) ist eine literarische Gattung mit Einleitung, Hauptteil und Schluss.

*»Beschreiben«* wird sozusagen auch auf der Kurzstrecke genutzt.

> Er beschrieb den Mann als klein und dick.

*»Schildern«* kann in den meisten, wenn nicht gar in allen Fällen durch *»beschreiben«* ersetzt werden. Das Umgekehrte gilt nicht.

> Beschreiben Sie mal den Hund da!¹

Hier wäre *»schildern«* unmöglich.

Bei Darstellung eines Aussehens (Person, Landschaft, Auto) ist *»beschreiben«* das Geeignete, bei der Wiedergabe von Erlebtem *»schildern«* (Ablauf eines Verkehrsunfalls).

<sub>¹Sprachlehrer zum Flüchtling (grob)</sub>

Comment: *Schildern Sie mal den Hund da* gefällt mir gut.

Answer (score 6):

*Schildern* kann man nur Vorgänge und Begebenheiten, nicht die *Eigenschaften* von Gegenständen und Personen - Also alles, was man in einem Aussagesatz über das Prädikat und adverbiale Konstruktionen ausdrücken würde.

*Beschreiben* wird man in erster Linie die Eigenschaften von Dingen und Personen, und erst in zweiter Linie Begebenheiten und Vorgänge (obwohl man sie durchaus *beschreiben kann*) - Also alles, was man in einem Aussagesatz über ein Substantiv und adjektivische Konstruktionen ausdrücken würde.

Answer (score 2):

"Beschreiben" ist meines Wissens mehr nüchtern, sachlich, objektiv, während "Schildern" mehr bewegt, bilderreich, subjektiv ist. Letzteres leitet sich dann ursprünglich auch ab
von mittelhochdeutsch "schiltære", ein Wappen bemalen.